# How to write long division in overleaf?

Tags: latex, division, overleaf

```
\usepackage{scalerel,mathtools}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}    
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow,pgffor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\PhantC}{\phantom{\colon}}
\newcommand{\CenterInCol}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\longdiv}{\smash{\mkern-0.43mu\vstretch{1.5}{\hstretch{.7}{|}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\arraycolsep=6pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}

\begin{array}{l@{\hskip\arraycolsep}l@{\hskip\arraycolsep}r}
 & & a_1= y_2x_4 - y_3x_1^2 + y_3x_4^2 - y_4x_1^3 + y_4x_4^3 \\
 & & a_2=-y_2x_4 - y_3x_4^2 - y_4x_4^3 \\ 
\cline{2-3}
 y_1+y_2x_4+y_3x_4^2+y_4x_4^3 & \longdiv & y_1y_2x_4 - y_1y_3x_1^2 +    
 y_1y_3x_4^2 - y_1y_4x_1^3 + y_1y_4x_4^3 + y_2^2x_1x_4 + 
 y_2y_3x_1x_4^2 + y_2y_4x_1x_4^3\\

-y_2x_1+y_2x_4-y_3x_1^2+y_3x_4^2-y_4x_1^3+y_4x_4^3 & \longdiv &





\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

I need some help in writing this long division as it is going out of the page.

The problem that I am facing while writing long division in latex is when the divisor and the dividend are 3 line long polynomials.In those cases my polynomials are going out of the page.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] including a document class

Comment: Is my example better now ?

Comment: No, we can't compile your code because there is no document class

Comment: This code is compiling in overleaf.Where are you compiling this ?

Comment: This code does not compile. Just because overleaf is good at hiding error messages does not mean it compiles! Already the first line will throw an error about `\usepackage before \documentclass. \usepackage{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write the dividend over 2 lines, just like you did for the divisor.
The following should hopefully stay within the margins of your page:

```tex
\[
\arraycolsep=6pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{l@{\hskip\arraycolsep}l@{\hskip\arraycolsep}r}
& & a_1= y_2x_4 - y_3x_1^2 + y_3x_4^2 - y_4x_1^3 + y_4x_4^3 \\
& & a_2=-y_2x_4 - y_3x_4^2 - y_4x_4^3 \\ 
\cline{2-3}
y_1+y_2x_4+y_3x_4^2+y_4x_4^3-y_2x_1
& \longdiv & y_1y_2x_4 - y_1y_3x_1^2 + y_1y_3x_4^2 - y_1y_4x_1^3 + y_1y_4x_4^3 \\
+y_2x_4-y_3x_1^2+y_3x_4^2-y_4x_1^3+y_4x_4^3
& \longdiv & + y_2^2x_1x_4 + y_2y_3x_1x_4^2 + y_2y_4x_1x_4^3
\end{array}
\]
```

This works for 12pt font on US letter paper with standard 1 inch margins, and on A4 paper with 2.5 cm margins.